# How to delete NSBezierPath

Tags: cocoa, quartz-graphics, quartz-2d

I have an `NSBezierPath` that I created and I called -stroke on it. How do I remove/delete it from the view without deallocating the object?

Answer (score 7):

A `-stroke` message tells the `NSBezierPath` to render itself in the current drawing context. If you've drawn a path in a view, and you want the stroked path to go away, just redraw the view without the path.

Comment: To add to this explanation somewhat: It's important to realize, when drawing on your view (or an image, etc.), you're not "adding a path object to the view object", you're using the information from the created path to draw it onto the view. Once drawn, you can't "remove" it - you'll have to redraw the view (or a given rectangle within it).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to temporary disable drawing, you can set `[NSColor clearColor]` before calling `stroke`.